# Requests to ipvsadm server hang in state SYN_RECV, direct requests to real server OK

Tags: reverse-proxy, ipvs

I have IPVS configured as:

```
$ ipvsadm --save
-A -t localhost:<port> -s rr
-a -t localhost:<port> -r <other_hostname>:<port> -m -w 1
```

It seems to be running:

```
$ ipvsadm
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  localhost:<port> rr
  -> <other_hostname>:<port>         Masq    1      1          0
```

but that `1` 'ActiveConn' hangs indefinitely, while a direct request  responds quickly and as expected:

```
$ curl https://<other_hostname>:<port>
<response>
$ curl https://localhost:<port>
[hangs]
```

---

Nothing seems wrong in `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg | grep IPVS
[ 4795.060820] IPVS: Registered protocols (TCP, UDP, SCTP, AH, ESP)
[ 4795.060932] IPVS: Connection hash table configured (size=4096, memory=64Kbytes)
[ 4795.061202] IPVS: ipvs loaded.
[ 4795.067663] IPVS: [rr] scheduler registered.
```

And nothing in `journalctl` from `ipvsadm`.

It seems to get stuck in state `SYN_RECV`:

```
$ ipvsadm -lnc
IPVS connection entries
pro expire state       source             virtual            destination
TCP 00:56  SYN_RECV    127.0.0.1:58322    127.0.0.1:<port>   <other_ip>:<port>
```

It seems that it isn't a configuration issue with the real server, since it's an issue with all modes (route, masquerade, tunnel) and testing with `httpbin.org` rather than my own.

---

What can cause a request to an IPVS to hang or fail when the 'real server'(s) underlying it respond OK, and how can it be debugged?

Comment: I initially asked on SO, but got a close vote suggesting it's a better fit here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040533/requests-to-ipvsadm-server-hang-directly-to-real-server-ok

Comment: It's a firewalling or networking issue.  Debugging will be via `tcpdump`.

Comment: @womble firewalling that affects ipvs but not 'direct' requests? The target IP address doesn't appear in `tcpdump` at all.

Comment: Its weird, I am having the same issue (completely same setup) with ip_vs on 5.4.0-45-generic with Ubuntu 20.04. I see SYN packets and the SYN_RECV state via ipvsadm, but these packets are never being answered. There is no asymmetric routing involved. If I connect to the VIP from the host it is assigned to, this works fine.

Comment: Wish I could help @M.Schmidt, but I never got to the bottom of it. I was using Arch, but also hadn't added any firewall or done anything to the network that I could see would affect IPVS traffic only.